# android nfc setting toggle listener

Tags: android, toggle, nfc

I want to listen nfc enable / disable in setting preferences so i add below code in my activity

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGE");
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            tv.setText("broadcast received :" + NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(MainActivity.this).isEnabled());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "broadcast received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

but it's look like ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGE is not working.

can anybody have an idea to listen state of nfc? please help..!!

Comment: not sure why but "android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGE" is working well with androidManifest insted of do filtering in activity???

Comment: how exactly do you use it in Android Manifest? are you using a specific category?

Comment: nope, it's simply work as an action with broadcast recivers

Answer (score 6):

The name of this Intent is "android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED", not "android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGE". Note the **D** on **CHANGED**.

Comment: To avoid such errors, try referencing the constant name via [`NfcAdapter.ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED).